# Variadic template candidate unmatched

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'm attempting to put together a generic method invoker (for a C++ OO/v8 bridge), using variadic template metaprogramming to build the parameter list, converting to native types, and finally execute the attached method, once the incoming param list is empty (and outgoing is therefore built):

```
template<typename... PARAMS>
class InvocationBuilder {
public:

void invoke(const Arguments &source, PARAMS&... params) {
    cout << "Invoke" << endl;
    (instance->*(method))(*params...);
}

template<class HEAD, class ... TAIL>
void invoke(const Arguments &source, PARAMS... params) {
    cout << "Expand" << endl;
    Type<HEAD> param(source[sizeof...(PARAMS)]);
    InvocationBuilder<PARAMS..., HEAD> builder;
    builder.template invoke<TAIL...>(source, params..., *param);
}
```

The Type class is merely a wrapper to create stack scoped variants of v8 parameters (so that, for instance, char* strings can be used while in scope during the invocation, but are automatically cleaned up once the call has returned).

Now, when the actual bridge invokes this, with a parameter list, using:

```
InvocationBuilder<> builder;
builder.template invoke<ARGS...>(args);
```

Where args is the v8::Arguments reference.

The compiler correctly chains each step of the parameter generation, but fails to match the non-templated invoke() method, to actually execute the native C++ method.

The error message is as follows:

```
include/link/function.hh: In member function 'void sjs::link::InstanceFunctionVariadic<CLASS, ARGS>::InvocationBuilder<PARAMS>::invoke(const v8::Arguments&, PARAMS ...) [with HEAD = int, TAIL = {}, PARAMS = {int, int}, CLASS = SomeClass, ARGS = {int, int, int}]':
include/link/function.hh:65:6:   recursively instantiated from 'void sjs::link::InstanceFunctionVariadic<CLASS, ARGS>::InvocationBuilder<PARAMS>::invoke(const v8::Arguments&, PARAMS ...) [with HEAD = int, TAIL = {int}, PARAMS = {int}, CLASS = SomeClass, ARGS = {int, int, int}]'
include/link/function.hh:65:6:   instantiated from 'void sjs::link::InstanceFunctionVariadic<CLASS, ARGS>::InvocationBuilder<PARAMS>::invoke(const v8::Arguments&, PARAMS ...) [with HEAD = int, TAIL = {int, int}, PARAMS = {}, CLASS = SomeClass, ARGS = {int, int, int}]'
include/link/function.hh:47:5:   instantiated from 'v8::Handle<v8::Value> sjs::link::InstanceFunctionVariadic<CLASS, ARGS>::run(const v8::Arguments&) [with CLASS = SomeClass, ARGS = {int, int, int}]'
test.cc:41:1:   instantiated from here
include/link/function.hh:65:6: error: no matching function for call to 'sjs::link::InstanceFunctionVariadic<SomeClass, int, int, int>::InvocationBuilder<int, int, int>::invoke(const v8::Arguments&, int&, int&, int)'
include/link/function.hh:65:6: note: candidate is:
include/link/function.hh:61:10: note: template<class HEAD, class ... TAIL> void sjs::link::InstanceFunctionVariadic<CLASS, ARGS>::InvocationBuilder::invoke(const v8::Arguments&, PARAMS ...) [with HEAD = HEAD, TAIL = {TAIL ...}, PARAMS = {int, int, int}, CLASS = SomeClass, ARGS = {int, int, int}]
```

The message clearly shows that the first three steps, for a C++ instance method void test(int a, int b, int c), are working correctly, extracting the parameters using Type and passing the results along - but I can't work out why the final invoke() is not being correctly used.

I've tried to fully specialize it, but then I get error messages about specialization outside of namespace scope (which I assume is because the method is a member of a templated class).

I've also tried shifting the incoming/outgoing parameter lists, so that the incoming is in the class variadic template, and the outgoing in the method to specialise the class for invocation instead - but I run into the "sorry, unimplemented" message about unpacking the variadic into the static  template.

I've also tried working around that by using a generic single variadic template, then specialising for the HEAD/TAIL case, and specialising for the empty set case, but then I get immediate ambiguity (probably because the HEAD/TAIL values are not actually passed as parameters - merely in the template).

But so far, no dice.  Anyone have any other ideas, or can explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Don't mix template- and non-template-overloads. Overload resolution is tricky and may not do what you think. You can call one guy `invoke_impl` or so.

Comment: The problem with that is I want the method to be an automatic termination of the parameter list recursion, rather than a specific additional case.

I have actually tried a separate case, using sizeof...(PARAMS) to identify whether the list is built, but it means the invocation method gets built for each of the sub-stages, with wrong parameter counts, and therefore gives compile errors.

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually see through this, so I shouldn't be saying anything. I can't see why you need non-static functions; typically such helper classes are done with only static member functions, since the helper itself has no and needs no state. Perhaps you're mixing responsibilities too much, but it's impossible for me to tell. I'm sure someone else will be able to provide some feedback that's actually useful.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of static is because its a sub class of a parent class, that contains (as instance variables) the specific instance, and method to be invoked.

I attempted to decouple these, and use static, but it just leads to a lack of clarity, as that instance, and method, then have to be passed through every stage of the parameter composition as well.

Comment: Should clarify the wrong terminology - its a contained within another class - not a sub class, so that it can use the container classes template parameters, and instance variables to reference the specific class instance, and method to be invoked, once the parameter list is built.

Comment: Yes, if I implicitly invoke it with invoke<TAIL...>, it causes g++ (4.61) to choke, with:

(error: expected primary-expression before '...' token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- you explicitly try to invoke a template
- your templated `invoke` always requires `PARAMS...` to be passed as function arguments

One possible alternative:

```
#include <functional>

template<class... Types> struct List {};

template<class... PARAMS> struct Invoker {
    typedef std::function<void (PARAMS&...)> Fn;
    Fn fn_;    
    Invoker(const Fn&& fn) : fn_(fn) {}

    void invoke(List<>, PARAMS&... params) {
        fn_(params...);
    }

    template<class HEAD, class... TAIL, class... ARGS>
    void invoke(List<HEAD, TAIL...>, ARGS... params) {
        HEAD param; // or your Type<HEAD> ... etc.
        invoke(List<TAIL...>(), params..., param);
    }
};

void f(int, int, int) {} // some function you want to call

int main() {
    Invoker<int,int,int> inv(&f);
    inv.invoke(List<int,int,int>());
}
```

... without a small compilable example of your use-case (with dummy-types etc.) it would be a bit time-consuming to make this match your code more closely.

Comment: Thank you - yes, that worked perfectly - using the struct to relate the variadic template parameter to an actual method param solved the issue for me, and removed the need for explicitly templating the call(s).